# Check whether the data in column1 lies in a range And add data in column 2

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R containing 2 columns. I want to check whether the data in column one lies in the following range: x>80,70

```
count1
   Var1    Freq
1  0.00000   7
2  10.00000  1
3  16.66667  1
4  30.95238  1
5  33.33333  2
```

Data frame contains 32 rows in total with values in column 1 ranging from 0 to 100.
output should be something like this :

```
    Var1      Freq
1   x<60      12
2   60<x<70   *something*
3   70<x<80   *something*
4   x>80      *something*
```

Comment: See `?cut` and `?findInterval`

Comment: For instance `xtabs(Freq ~ cut(Var1, c(0, 60, 70, 80, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE), count1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `datatable` library

df is your dataframe :

```
breaks <- c(0,60,70,80,Inf)
setDT(df)
df[,list(SUM = sum(freq)),by = list(VAR=cut(var1,breaks = breaks))][order(VAR)]
```

With `dplyr` library :

```
 df %>% 
     group_by(VAR = cut(var1, breaks = breaks)) %>% 
     summarise(SUM = sum(freq)) %>%
     arrange(VAR)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.